# "Cannot evaluate expression..." error

Tags: visual-studio-2010

All of a sudden I got the following error when debugging applications in Visual Studio 2010 beta 2.

> "Cannot evaluate expression because a
>   thread is stopped at a point where
>   garbage collection is impossible,
>   possibly because the code is
>   optimized"

Almost every property or field in the watch window displays this message. Does anyone know what is going on? and how to get rid of it?

The checkbox "Optimize code" on the project properties build tab is turned off.

Comment: I'm having the very same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few day I noticed the error was gone… No idea what caused or resolved it…

Answer (score 6):

Here is a [link](http://www.mail-archive.com/advanced-dotnet@discuss.develop.com/msg12883.html) to a discussion on this issue. Apparently when function arguments are structs, and the total memory needed on the stack to call the function exceeds some magical number visual studio debugger pukes.

**Quote**

> I think the sum total sizes of the "references" for all the objects in the
>   struct and the additional parameters on the method was greater than 256
>   bytes.
>
> I got word back from MS on this issue:
>
> "...generally speaking, when the total size of the arguments passed to a
>   callee function is larger than 256 bytes, JIT will make the caller function
>   partially interruptible.  In a partially interruptible code, not every
>   location in the code is a GC safe point.  Therefore, it might be unsafe to
>   evaluate expression at certain locations.  When this happens you get [the
>   error message]."
>
> So it seems that even since the fields were references, the sum of all them
>   exceeded the 256 byte **limit** for the debugger.

I also have this [link](http://www.opentk.com/node/1460) from OpenTK framework discussion.

**Quote**

> I did some digging and it appears that the problem springs from the fact that Math data structures such as Matrix or Vector are of type "struct".
>   C# has a limitation for value types saying that they should not exceed 256 bytes of data when passed as arguments to functions,
>   **unless they are passed by reference**. Non compliance to that produces uninterruptable code in debug mode.
>   The problem should be solved if the formentioned data structures are transformed from structs to classes.

Comment: +1 This is the **CORRECT** answer. Changing `ByVal` to `ByRef` resolved the issue.

Comment: The answer is correct.

Calculate the size of the struct. Most probably it is over 256 bytes.
In the case I encountered I used in the struct a lot of decimal properties which summed passed the 256 bytes limit.
A refactor from decimal to int was all that it was needed to make things work.

Answer (score 0):

I got this too, when I hit a NullReferenceException from a 3rd party control.

In this one case, I found that if I set a breakpoint **before** I hit the exception, I could then single step through the rest of the code without seeing the problem.

No idea why, but this worked for me - in this case at least.

Also, I was not doing anything with structs, as mentioned by @ja72.  So it seems this error can occur in other situations as well.