# Cannot evaluate expression error in ONE project for years

Tags: visual-studio

Just tired to see this error every time for years only in ONE project: "Cannot evaluate expression because a thread is stopped at a point where garbage collection is impossible, possibly because the code is optimized"

Almost every property or field displays this message. From vs2005+.net2.0 to vs2008+.net3.5 now. Does anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: There must be something wrong in your environment. I've never seen that error before.

Comment: It happens on different environments... I'm working with this solution on 2 machines and also checked on other developers machines. Seems that solution issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same problem as [this StackOverfow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961123/cannot-evaluate-expression-error). In that case it seems to be an inbuilt limit to the size of structs used within the method. The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4127098/6091) provides links to two discussions of the issue.